# Question regarding Kernel Density Estimation bandwidth selection (Scott's rule)

Tags: nonparametric, kernel-smoothing

I'm studying KDE and got trouble understanding Scott's rule or Silverman's rule for bandwidth selection.

I saw that the optimal bandwidth is the value that minimizes Mean Integrated Squared Error (MISE).

$MISE = \int E(\hat f(x)-f(x) )^2 d{x} $

But MISE formula can't be used directly since they involve the unknown, real density function $f(x)$.

Therefore, Scott's or Silverman's rule of thumb assumes Gaussian distribution for the unknown density $f(x)$ in order to find optimal bandwidth.

My doubt/question is:

1. Non-parametric method like KDE is a distribution-free method, which **do not rely on assumptions that the data are drawn from a given parametric family of probability distributions**.
   But since Scott or Silverman's rule assumes Gaussian distribution for the unknown density $f(x)$, it seems like a contradiction for me.
2. Does Scott or Silverman's rule assumes that the kernel function to estimate density is also Gaussian?

Many thanks :)

Comment: Scott’s rule assumes $h_n$ to be propor-tional to $d·n^{\frac{-1}{
m+4}}$ where $d$ is the standard deviation of the time series, 
$m$ is dimension of $x$